# Нахождение крайних точек по координатам

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Не могу найти, составить алгоритм нахождения, к примеру, правой нижней точки по координатам в таком массиве

```
(100,100),(200,100),(150,200),(100,200).
```

Если соединить эти точки линиями, выйдет прямоугольная трапеция, и мне отсюда нужно найти правую нижнюю (150,200) точку. Раньше, когда имел дело только с прямоугольниками (а не трапециями, как в этом случае), в цикле у всех точек искал максимальную координату, и потом искал точку с такими координатами, но в данном случае максимальными будут координаты (200,200), и точки с такими - нету...

Comment: мне кажется или (150,200) - это права верхняя точка?

Comment: потому что Вы математик, а @metalurgus - начинающий программист и у него ось у направлена сверху вниз.:)

Comment: Я так понимаю, что единственный интерес вопроса в том, что будет правильным ответом в случае набора, состоящего из двух точек `{(150, 200), (200, 150)}.` А дальше уже вариации на тему сортировки в `coordinatewise` порядке.

Comment: - Самый универсальный вариант *(поскольку у вас написано "к примеру", а значит, возможно, подразумевается какая-либо дополнительная логика)* - придумать метрику "хорошести" относительно исходных условий и выбрать из последовательности точек точку с наибольшим значением этой метрики.

- Разумеется, такую метрику можно придумать не всегда, да и не каждый из придуманных вариантов, строго говоря, будет метрикой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно последовательно пройти по всем точкам, проверяя их на "правость" и "нижнесть" одновременно. Очередную точку следует считать "более лучшим" кандидатом на роль самой правой и нижней в том случае, если у неё хотя бы одна из координат имеет более правое или более нижнее значение, чем у наилучшего на данный момент кандидата, при условии, что другая координата не ухудшает положение (т.е. меньше или равна соответствующей координате у лучшего). Та точка, которая окажется наилучшей в самом конце, как раз и будет самой правой и нижней.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: правда, если взять такой вариант `(100,100) (100,200) (101,101) (200,100)` - то я даже не знаю, какой угол будет правым нижним. Правда в этом случае не будет пересечения.

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю(for [@iranda](/users/7905/iranda) начал с большой буквы) следующую идею сортировки подобного массива с помощью js:

```
var array = [{x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 100}, {x: 150, y: 200}, {x: 100, y: 200}];
array.sort(function(a,b){ return a.y - b.y || a.x - b.x });
```

Результат:

```
[{x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 100}, {x: 100, y: 200}, {x: 150, y: 200}]
```

Т.о. получаем :

```
array[0] - левая нижняя
array[1] - правая нижняя
array[2] - левая верхняя
array[3] - правая верхняя
```

P.S. **для сильно кривых трапеций алгоритм недееспособен**

Comment: Спасибо, ваш и предыдущий ответ решили мою задачу!

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю алгоритм.
Есть четыре точки. Значит можно соединить их попарно двумя отрезками тремя способами (`1-2, 3-4; 1-3,2-4; 1-4,2-3`). В одном случае из трех эти отрезки будут пересекаться. Найдя точку пересечения (которая будет неким центром), сравниваем координаты с ней. Если обе координаты нужной точки больше координат точки пересечение, то это и будет ниже-правее (в системе координат с осью у вниз).

Если же для точки одна с координат будет совпадать с координатами центральной точки - у нас ромб.

Если же прямоугольник будет вырожденным в треугольник или отрезок, то метод конечно не будет работать, но эти случаи легко отбросить.

Нахождение пересечения двух отрезков - классическая задача и много раз разобрана, например: [1](http://delphid.dax.ru/www/exampl34.htm) и [2](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=53e3d700aff620a5).

Answer (score 0):

Можно пройтись по всем точкам проверяя их на максимально правый и нижний, но может случится так что 2 точки которые проверяются на правость могут быть равны и это надо учесть.

```
const arr = [{x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 100}, {x: 150, y: 200}, {x: 100, y: 200}];
let index = 0;
let minX = arr[0].x;
let maxY = arr[0].y;
arr.forEach((item, i) => {
  if (item.y > maxY || (item.y === maxY && item.x < minX)) {
    maxY = item.y;
    minX = item.x
    index = i;
  }
});
```

index будет равен индексу самому правому и нижнему углу, но учтите что именно самому правому нижнему, т.е может оказаться точка ниже но не правее